# How to draw filled gl_quads Open_GL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

So it's my first time working with OpenGL library and so far I have this code:

```
glColor3f(1, 0.1, 0.1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.3, 0.7);
glVertex2f(0.55, 0.45);
glVertex2f(1.0, 0.45);
glEnd();
```

It is drawing an empty "form" only with red edges, I want it filled with color inside as well.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
```

See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml

Comment: `GL_FILL` is the default for the polygon mode, so there should be no need to set it unless it was previously set to a different value.